How many jet fighters is Azerbaijan purchasing?

JF-17C multirole aircrafts presented to President Ilham Aliyev

This presidential website confirms that Azerbaijan has purchased JF-17 from Pakistan.
Some sites suggest that it was a $1.6 billion deal.
However, the number of aircraft is not specified.
How many jet fighters is Azerbaijan purchasing from Pakistan?
What will be the unit-price?

This says 24 jets: https://defense-update.com/20240905_aerospace.html

Azerbaijan is set to significantly enhance its air force capabilities by acquiring 24 JF-17 Thunder fighter jets from Pakistan in a $1.6 billion deal.


what will be the unit-price?

@user366312 - $1.6B / 24 = $66.7M each. But remember, a fighter jet is totally useless without all the other stuff. Parts, maintenance manuals, maintenance hardware, mechanic training, etc, etc, etc. Presumably, the $1.6B would encompass all of that.
